# Is it better to translate to whole canvas, or to change the position of elements drawn on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with around 20 images drawn on it, at certain positions. Let's just call them objects.

I have a player, right in the centre of the canvas. When this player moves, it stays centered, and all the objects drawn on the canvas will move, instead of the player. Thus, it is creating the illusion the player is moving. While of course, it is the only thing *not* moving.

Would it be more efficient to instead of changing all the x and y of all of the objects to make them move, translate the whole canvas context? This way I move one (quite big) thing, instead of 20 separate objects, *and*, on top of that: I wouldn't have to redraw all the images as well.

Comment: "I wouldn't have to redraw all the images as well.". How come? If you redraw them at different positions, you need to ... redraw them. No matter how you do the change in position. As for perfs difference between `fillRect(x + 20, y +30, w, h); fillRect(x1 + 20, y1 + 30, w, h);` and `translate(20, 30); fillRect(x, y, w, h); fillRect(x1,  y1, w, h);`, there isn't any. It just boils down to preference as to which is cleaner.

Comment: They'd be drawn at the same position, since its the canvas which shifted. But having to redraw them again because of that is a different story. Would make sense if they'd have to be redrawn anyway. I'm not sure how it works, but in my mind it'd make sense if moving the canvas should be more efficient since the images are already there and loaded.

Comment: It's not the canvas that you do translate, it's the context's current tranform matrix (CTM). This CTM only has effect on **new** drawings. So you would need to redraw your whole scene for it to be translated. To redraw your scene, you need to redraw each elements in it. That boils down to the exact same operations.

Answer (score 1):

### Set the transform.

Translate creates a matrix and then multiplies the current transform by the translation transform.

The current transform is always applied to all rendered items even if you don't set translate, scale, or rotate.

It is most efficient (in terms of performance and source code complexity) to maintain a shadow of the current transform and avoid the overhead of creating a translate matrix and then multiplying the current transform (happens under the hood).

All you need is an array of 6 values.

```
const view = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];  // Matrix representing the view.
```

This represents the view matrix. First two values are the direction and scale of the x axis (in this case across the canvas from left to right). The second two are the direction and scale of the y axis (in this case down the canvas). The last two are the x, y position of the origin (where, in pixele, if you draw at 0, 0 it will be drawn on the canvas)

You could also use a [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) which has some handy functionality for more advanced needs, though for basic tasks (translate, scale, rotate) using an array is more performant.

If you have a character...

```
const character = {x: 1000, y: 1000};  // position of character
```

...if you want it centered to the canvas, you need the canvas size and then set the last two values (origin) of the view matrix

```
view[4] = -character.x + canvas.width * 0.5;
view[5] = -character.y + canvas.height * 0.5;
```

You can then use

```
ctx.setTransform(view[0], view[1], view[2], view[3], view[4], view[5]);
// or use spread operator
ctx.setTransform(...view);
```

And then draw all the object at their position.

Using [setTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) and you don't need to save the current state or mess around with translating from and then back. To restore the default transform just set the transform to the identity matrix. eg `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`

Now you do not have to add the translation to each world object making all rendered objects independent of the view.

As the view is a full 2D matrix you can also scale and rotate the view with very little extra effort.

### Example

A simple demo that uses a matrix called view to follow a character moving in the world.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const rndI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const rndSize = (size) => [rndI(size * 0.2, size), rndI(size * 0.2, size)];
const Vec2 = (x, y) => ({x, y});
const view = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];  // Matrix representing the view.
const Obj = (pos, col, w, h) => ({pos, col, w, h});
const character = Obj(Vec2(0, 0), "#000", 20, 20);  // position of character 

function setView(pos) {
  view[4] = -pos.x + canvas.width * 0.5;
  view[5] = -pos.y + canvas.height * 0.5;
}
function applyView(view) {
  ctx.setTransform(...view);
}

function drawWorld(objs) {
  for(const o of objs) {
    ctx.fillStyle = o.col;
    ctx.fillRect(o.pos.x - o.w * 0.5, o.pos.y - o.h * 0.5, o.w, o.h);
  }
}

function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // set default transform to clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    time *= 0.2;
    const pAngA = time / 1000;
    const pAngB = time / 337;
    character.pos.x = Math.cos(pAngA) * 600 + Math.cos(pAngB) * 400;
    character.pos.y = Math.sin(pAngA) * 600 + Math.sin(pAngB) * 400;
    
    setView(character.pos);
    applyView(view);
    drawWorld(world);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
const world = [
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0AF", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0AF", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0AF", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#CA0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#0A0", ...rndSize(630)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  Obj(Vec2(rndI(-1000, 1000), rndI(-1000, 1000)), "#580", ...rndSize(130)),
  character,
];
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="540" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Damn this looks quite promising. Do you have more sources where I can get detailed explanations about JS, browser games? You seem to know your stuff. I will look into this and get to understand what's happening precisely. Tysm!

Comment: @rewfsdv https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Introduction is a good place to start.

Comment: What's to back all these "more performant" claims? There is no reason an Array would be more performant than a DOMMatrix, on the contrary, your Array has to be parsed to a valid DOMMatrix, while the DOMMatrix can be used as is. Same for CTM vs manually adjusting the coords, as you state it's done intrrnally anyway, so that's just the same. This leaves only personal opinion about which is easier to maintain, which completly depends on the project.

Comment: @Kaiido Your claim that *"...Array has to be parsed to a valid DOMMatrix,"* is nonsense see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#current-transformation-matrix 
 And considering performance try `A=new DOMMatrix([2,0,0,2,10,10)`, and `B=[2,0,0,2,10,10];` then time the calls `ctx.setTransform(A)` and `ctx.setTransform(...B)`. The array is an order of magnitude faster. Compare instantiation of A and B, B is, dur, 100+ times faster. Now if one were to exploit the fact that 99% of use cases use uniform transforms, and many matrix operations can be greatly simplified well....

Comment: The specs do describe a behavior, they don't describe an implementation. Performance wise it makes a lot more sense for a graphic engine to use a matrix class internally. Doing a mapping DOMMatrix->internal Matrix will most certainly have a fast path. Going from the arguments everytime has to go first through the IDL parser at least, and will probably not have that fast path. Your micro-benchmark only measures the time spent synchronously on the CPU. Your drawing operations are not necessarily measured by it. And anyway these are so minor operations that they can completely be disregarded.

Comment: @Kaiido The IDL is just a set of offsets into the internal matrix (CanvasTransform) and represents zero runtime overhead, the matrix already exists (instantiated at getContext) . There is so much more to CG than rendering (granted simple play through animations are the exception) Code needs to interact with the scene and transformation matrices (single instances and trees) are the primary tool, representing a major operational component of interactive CG. When it comes to CG performance is king, disregarded and it will bite.

Comment: Why would GC be any different between an Array and a DOMMatrix? In both cases you'd keep them around and it won't be collected.

Comment: @Kaiido CG (Computer Graphics) not GC.

Comment: Then what are you saying? The internal matrix is held by Skia for instance in Chromium. Both the Array and the DOMMatrix are irrelevant there. Skia will only use its own Matrix. Using an Array or a DOMMatrix is irrelevant. And doing translate(23,23); lineTo(0,0); is just the same as lineTo(23,23).

Comment: are Rest parameters efficient tho? @Blindman67

Comment: @rewfsdv Currently rest parameters `setTransform(...view)` does slightly out-performs passing each array item `setTransform(view[0], view[1], view[2], view[3], view[4], view[5])` as indexing array items has an overhead on chromium (thought firefox indexes' arrays faster however I have no uptodate stats for firefox). Note that over the past few years the performance of rest parameters have varied wildly but has stanbalized of late 2022.

Comment: So would you say all in all this is on a larger scale, or smaller scale a better solution? Using matrix transformations